# Using SMTP for sending e-mail with C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, email, smtp

I was trying to send an email in c language but after handshaking, ack message and printing message sent, it does not send mail to my inbox. My whole code executed succesfully. Could you help, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#define BUFFEr_SIZE 4096

void error(char *msg)
{
  perror(msg);
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int sockfd, portno, n;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
 struct hostent *server;

 char buffer[BUFFEr_SIZE];
 if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
 }
 portno = atoi(argv[2]);
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");

n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE\n");
printf("EHLO");

strcpy(buffer,"ehlo smtp.gmail.com\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/    

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE EHLO\n");
printf("AUTH");

strcpy(buffer,"AUTH LOGIN\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE AUTH\n");
printf("AUTH UID");

strcpy(buffer,"xxxx@gmail.com");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE UID\n");
printf("AUTH PWD");

strcpy(buffer,"xxxxxx");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/

printf("MAIL FROM");

strcpy(buffer,"MAIL FROM: xxxxx@gmail.com");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/

 printf("MAIL TO");


strcpy(buffer,"RCPT TO: aaaaa@gmail.com");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/       

/*------------------------------*/
printf("DONE MAILTO\n");

printf("DATA");

strcpy(buffer,"DATA\r\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,"Subject: test\r\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,"SMTP MAIL TOOL TEST WORKS!!!\r\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,"\n\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,".\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));


/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/ 
printf("SON DONE");
strcpy(buffer,"quit\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
puts(buffer);

/*------------------------------*/

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT is here:

220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP bh6sm124854736wjb.0 - gsmtp

DONE EHLO250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [85.98.184.204]

250-SIZE 35882577

250-8BITMIME

250-STARTTLS

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-PIPELINING

250-CHUNKING

250 SMTPUTF8

DONE EHLO AUTH451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821 bh6sm124854736wjb.0 - gsmtp

DONE AUTH

AUTH UID

DONE UID

AUTH PWD

MAIL FROM

MAIL TO

DONE MAILTO

DATASON DONE

Comment: If your code "executed successful", why do you ask?

Comment: What does your program output when you run it?  Also, you should use `send` and `recv` for sockets, not `write` and `read`.

Comment: And learn proper indentation. That code is quite unreadable.

Comment: Can you show the output of your program? You suggest that it works (or doesn't detect an error), which means there's no obvious problem with your C code, and it's the SMTP which needs debugging.

Comment: @dbush I tried these but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here `451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821` is the error. And how to fix it (read RFC 2821).

Answer (score 1):

After you send the `AUTH LOGIN` command, the SMTP server returns with `451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821`.  Looking at [RFC 2181](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), this command does not exist.

This command is an extension to SMTP, which this mail server does not support.  If you remove the authentication commands, it should work.

Also, when continuing to test, be sure to look at the output to your program to ensure that the server doesn't return any more errors.  If it does, check the standards as to why you're getting those errors.

Comment: The server's `EHLO` reply is reporting support for `STARTTLS`.  If you send a `STARTTLS` command, complete an SSL/TLS handshake, and then send `EHLO` again, the server is allowed to update its capabilities, which usually includes enabling support for otherwise-unsecure `AUTH` commands, like `AUTH LOGIN`.

Comment: I removed AUTH LOGIN part, but server does not reply the other parts.

Comment: @UtkuGökcan: you can't send email through Gmail without authentication, and you can't authenticate without creating a secure SSL/TLS session first. That is how Gmail's server works. That said, your code in doing anything to validate the server's responses, all you are doing is sending arbitrary buffers and reading arbitrary buffers, but that is not how SMTP works. There is a defined protocol that you are ignoring.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I got it your idea and it is logical but where should I add STARTTLS command?

Comment: @UtkuGökcan: Read [RFC 3207](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3207). You send `STARTTLS` after `EHLO` (which tells you if `STARTTLS` is supported) and any time before you need to send something sensitive for the first time, like authentication credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send addresses as:

```
  MAIL FROM:<userx@y.foo.org>
  RCPT TO:<userc@d.bar.org>
```

Comment: I have these adress' in code block but I write here as xxx@gmail.com. But thanks your answer.

Comment: Im sorry. I could not understand what you mean. But after changing, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol violation is simply because of the +1 in the second line:

```
strcpy(buffer,"AUTH LOGIN\n");
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
```

You are sending google "AUTH LOGIN\n\0" - \0 should not be there.

You would still find that google won't allow you to send your password over a plain unencrypted SMTP connection (i.e. without STARTTLS and actually connecting over TLS), but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. I have intentionally put all the code in 'main' function. I know it is bad practice and not professional but it is just for a demo.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

#include "base64_codec.h"

#define BUFLEN 4096

/*void InitOpenSSL()
{
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
}*/

int main()
{
    int sock;
    char *host, *cmd, *ip;
    char* enc_cmd;
    char recvbuf[BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    size_t out_len;

    struct hostent* hent;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";

    printf("Attempting to connect to %s...\n", host);
    //
    hent = gethostbyname(host);
    if(hent == NULL)
    {
        printf("gethostbyname failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("gethostbyname succeeded!\n");
    ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)hent->h_addr_list[0]);
    printf("Host IP: %s\n", ip);
    //
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        printf("socket failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("socket succeeded!\n");
    //
    bzero(&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(587);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    //
    iResult = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if(iResult < 0)
    {
        printf("connect failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("connect succeeded\n");
    //
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = recv(sock, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1, 0);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "EHLO smtp-mail.outlook.com\r\n";
    iResult = send(sock, cmd, strlen(cmd), 0);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    //
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = recv(sock, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1, 0);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "STARTTLS\r\n";
    iResult = send(sock, cmd, strlen(cmd), 0);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    //
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = recv(sock, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1, 0);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    // OpenSLL region
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    if(SSL_library_init() < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not initialise SSL library!\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("SSL Library initialised\n");
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    if(ctx == NULL)
    {
        printf("ctx failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("ctx done!\n");
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    if(ssl == NULL)
    {
        printf("ssl failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("ssl done!\n");
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
    iResult = SSL_connect(ssl);
    if(iResult < 0)
    {
        printf("SSL connect failed!\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("SSL connect succeeded!\n");
    cmd = "EHLO smtp-mail.outlook.com\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    //
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write faile\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "[Your-email]";
    enc_cmd = base64_encode(cmd, strlen(cmd), &out_len);
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, enc_cmd, out_len);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    cmd = "\r\n";
    SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "[Your password]";
    enc_cmd = base64_encode(cmd, strlen(cmd), &out_len);
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, enc_cmd, out_len);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    cmd = "\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "MAIL FROM: <Your mail>\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) sent: %d\n", iResult);
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "RCPT TO: <recipient email>\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "DATA\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=\"977d81ff9d852ab2a0cad646f8058349\"\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Subject: Test Mail\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "--977d81ff9d852ab2a0cad646f8058349\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Hi Me,=0A=0AThis is an empty file.=0A=0ARegards,=0A<ME>=0A=0A---- =0ASent using Guerrillamail.com =0ABlock or report abuse : https://www.guerrillamail.com//abuse/?a=3DUVJzDA8SW6Q1mwa14nUTcwfCX9ne0dhd=0A\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "--977d81ff9d852ab2a0cad646f8058349\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"details.txt\"\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "U2FtcGxlIFRleHQu\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "\r\n--977d81ff9d852ab2a0cad646f8058349--\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    //
    cmd = "\r\n.\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    cmd = "QUIT\r\n";
    iResult = SSL_write(ssl, cmd, strlen(cmd));
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_write failed\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    bzero(recvbuf, BUFLEN);
    iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_read failed: %d\n", errno);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
    //
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    printf("SSL closed!\n");
    iResult = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    if(iResult == 0)
    {
        printf("SSL shutdown in progress...\n");
    }
    iResult = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    if(iResult == 1)
    {
        printf("SSL shutdown succeeded\n");
    }
    if(iResult == -1)
    {
        printf("SSL shutdown failed!\n");
    }
    //
    iResult = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    if(iResult == -1)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", errno);
        //return -1;
    }
    printf("shutdown succeeded\n");
    iResult = close(sock);
    if(iResult < 0)
    {
        printf("Error occurred while closing socket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard job debugging a 5 year old scribble.  Basically, the program should also check at least the first digit of the response to know whether to proceed, even after DATA.  Nowadays most servers accept EHLO, GMail certainly does.  (Albeit the program accepts a hostname, we know from the 220 salutation that it is GMail.)  The EHLO argument is supposed to be the name of the client, not of the server.  Anyway, with a few corrections, a naive server could accept the message sent that way.  A server with decent anti-spam provisions won't.